# Trying to subset data and then drop levels of all but 5 specific ones

Tags: r

trying to subset 2 columns and then select only certain states in order to plot them against each other `(CA,NY,PA,FL,TX)`

I have 2 columns: `States` and `Tuition`

I created

```
states <- mydata[,c("state","tuition")
```

to get a df of just these two. I cant figure out how to drop the levels of all other ones. Initially I thought I could subset further with

```
Top5<- subset(states, states == "TX", "PA", "NY", "FL", "CA")
```

but was met with

> Error in drop && length(x) == 1L : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Top5<- subset(states, states %in% c("TX", "PA", "NY", "FL", "CA"))
```